# Returning JSON object or String from a JAX-RS method depending on a query parameter

Tags: java, json, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS servlet and I would like to return a JSON object for GET queries to the URL `/upgrade/somePath` but a `String` for GET queries to `/upgrade/somePath?count=true`. My problem is that this method cannot return two different types based on the query parameter. I tried to map a different method to a specific URL `@Path("/upgrade/somePath?count=true")` but Jersey was not happy to serve that.

```
@Path("upgrade")
public class UpgradeMock
{
    @GET
    @Path("somePath")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public UpgradePackageList getPackages(@QueryParam("count") Boolean count)
```

Comment: I think you should change even the response's Content-Type header according to that magical query parameter.

Comment: Why don't you use the path `/upgrade/somePath/count` for the second Resource?

Comment: Good idea and this will be the solution. I have these patterns from the specification which needs to be modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot achieve this using Jersey. If this way of working is a must (i.e. the specification) you should change your method to return a `String` and take JSON serialization into your hands by invoking Jackson's JSON serializer manually.